# why dose python code 'print(np.array([1355742581.0])[0] < torch.LongTensor([1355742616.0])[0])' output False?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

As described in the title, when comparing two timestamp using the following python code, I got an unexpected result, which should be True instead of Fasle, can anyone help explain this problem? Many thanks!

```
print(np.array([1355742581.0])[0] < torch.LongTensor([1355742616.0])[0])
```

Comment: Please put the code in the question, so you can format it readably.

Comment: Note that the inequality is false even if you swap the terms. You tested that `a < b` is `tensor(False)`, but `b < a` is also `tensor(False)`

Comment: Note that the np array is unnecessary (comparing np ararys and tensors isn't supported anyway). You would get the same result if you used `1355742581.0` as a Python float directly. For `a=1355742581.0` and `b=torch.LongTensor([1355742616.0])`, both `a<b` and `b<a` are `tensor([False])`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when comparing "integer tensor" and "float value other than tensor", PyTorch forcibly converts both to float32. In other words, the comparison you made is implicitly converted as follows.

```py
torch.FloatTensor([1355742581.0]) < torch.FloatTensor([1355742616.0])
# tensor([False])
```

The reason why this comparison is False is because both numbers are too large to be represented as float32, so they are rounded.

```
torch.FloatTensor([1355742581.0]).item()  # 1355742592.0
torch.FloatTensor([1355742616.0]).item()  # 1355742592.0
```

(If you don't understand why this is happening, please research about floating-point numbers.)

As evidence that this problem is due to precision, the result will be flipped if you add a number that is added to the upper bits.

```
np.array([1355742581.0])[0] < torch.LongTensor([1355742616.0 + 128])[0]
# tensor(True)
```

To avoid this problem, either make the right side explicitly DoubleTensor or make the left side DoubleTensor.

```
np.array([1355742581.0])[0] < torch.LongTensor([1355742616.0]).to(torch.float64)[0]
# tensor(True)

torch.DoubleTensor(np.array([1355742581.0]))[0] < torch.LongTensor([1355742616.0])[0]
# tensor(True)
```